# AWS Glue Scala, output one file with partitions

Tags: scala, pyspark, data-science, etl, aws-glue

There are lots of questions addressing this with python solutions, but having issues finding anything for Glue. Understood both leverage pyspark, but I'm getting compilation errors when I try to adapt python-based solutions to Scala. Wanted to both ask the question and get a simple reference for anyone else with the same issue.

Basically I generate my output like this

```
val datasource0 = DynamicFrame(data, glueContext).withName("datasource0").withTransformationContext("datasource0")
val datasink2 = glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(connectionType = "s3", options = JsonOptions(Map("path" -> "s3://sf_path")),format = "parquet", transformationContext = "datasink2").writeDynamicFrame(datasource0)
```

Pyspark being pyspark it generates multiple output files for this transformation. How can I modify my job to only create one output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `repartition` on your Scala `DynamicFrame`. The number of partitions equals the number of output files. More information on that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-dynamicframe-class.html#glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-dynamicframe-class-defs-repartition).

Code example: `val repartitionedDataSource1 = datasource1.repartition(1)`

Comment: For the following dataframe definition

val datasource0 = DynamicFrame(data, glueContext).withName("datasource0").withTransformationContext("datasource0")

Where do I leverage the repartition function? Is it like 

var repatriatedData = repartition(datasource0)

Also does that come from a library or is it like a supported function?

Comment: Oh, nevermind figured it out. For future users, this is how you do it 

    var repartitionedDataSource1 = datasource1.repartition(1)

Thanks Robert!!!

Comment: No problem Ronald, I will add the line of code to my answer :)